# How to add custom chars before IPs in a file with 178.000 lines?

Tags: file, apache2, etl

I have a text file with 178.000 lines of blacklisted IPs (12 MB) from [myip.ms](http://myip.ms/files/blacklist/general/full_blacklist_database.zip) in this format:

```
1.2.81.113           # 2014-09-10, 1.2.81.113, CHN, 51
1.2.82.108           # 2014-09-10, 1.2.82.108, CHN, 51
1.2.83.179           # 2014-09-11, 1.2.83.179, CHN, 51
1.2.86.210           # 2014-09-07, 1.2.86.210, CHN, 51
1.2.109.22           # 2014-09-06, 1.2.109.22, CHN, 51
```

Now I need to add "Require not ip " before each line like this:

```
Require not ip 1.2.81.113            # 2014-09-10, 1.2.81.113, CHN, 51
Require not ip 1.2.82.108            # 2014-09-10, 1.2.82.108, CHN, 51
Require not ip 1.2.83.179            # 2014-09-11, 1.2.83.179, CHN, 51
Require not ip 1.2.86.210            # 2014-09-07, 1.2.86.210, CHN, 51
Require not ip 1.2.109.22            # 2014-09-06, 1.2.109.22, CHN, 51
```

How do I achieve this best with lowest effort to meet my apache configuration or is there a better way to include the blacklist?

```
<Directory /var/www/>
<RequireAll>
    Require all granted
    # IP Blacklists
    Include full_blacklist_database.txt
</RequireAll>
</Directory>
```

Comment: So your looking for a way to append a string at the start of every line?

Comment: Either append a string at the start of every line or include the file as it is into apache config and deny the IPs directly in the config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java you can do this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class StringAppender {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fileIn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the path to the file");
    try{
        if(new File(fileIn).exists()){
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileIn));

            String tmp;
            while((tmp = br.readLine()) != null)
                sb.append("Require not ip " + tmp + "\n");

            br.close();
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileIn + ".new.txt"));
            out.write(sb.toString());
            out.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done! New file saved as: " + fileIn + ".new.txt");
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Requested file doesn't exist!");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unable to perform changes!");
    }
}
}
```

The precompiled version can be downloaded [here](http://www7.zippyshare.com/v/2r2qZ2Yj/file.html). To run it cd into the dir and execute `java StringAppender`

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example in python to add "Require not ip " in front of each line.

```
fr = open("/tmp/full_blacklist_database.txt", "r")
fw = open("/tmp/full_blacklist_database_require_not_ip.txt", "w")

for line in fr.readlines():
    fw.write("Require not ip " + line.strip() + "\n")

fr.close();
fw.close();
```

The file `full_blacklist_database_require_not_ip.txt` will have the required result.

After that you can copy the file content to your apache configuration file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an advanced file editor as [Notepd++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.7.5.html) then follow the example [here](http://www.question-defense.com/2010/07/29/append-text-to-each-line-in-notepad-prefix-text-to-every-line-in-notepad) changing the way at point 4 of the example with this one:

[image]

The result is the following:

[YourDB](http://www.magellano.us/eurobed/full_blacklist_database.zip)